# How to sort only selected desktop icons by name? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop, icons, sorting

I am running Windows 10, and I have many icons on my desktop. I would like to sort some of them (by name/date/etc), but when I **Right click** on my desktop and then do **Sort By > Name** *all* of the icons get rearranged. How can I only sort/mass rearrange *selected* icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/), a piece of software that allows you to group your desktop icons, appears to have the ability to sort its groups individually.

Comment: Is there a way to sort icons on the raw desktop, without any additional software? Is there a way to just apply a sort to selected files/folders instead of all files/folders on the desktop?